# Can QTP test cases be written in Java?

Tags: java, qtp

I've done a lot of poking around on the web for the answer to this question and have come up dry. I've seen in use a library for supposedly handling this, junit4QTP, but no one seems to know the location of said library.

What I hope to accomplish is being able to write QTP test cases in Java and then making the execution call from either the java code or QTP itself.

Please let me know if anyone has experience doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

As I understand from the title though that would "port" only funcionality for unit testing right?

Also I found http://jqtp.blogspot.com/ but you have to be invited to see it...